# Slide Div off screen instead of fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get this to work however I cannot find a solution.

Currently I have Divs sliding from the top of the screen, and then fading out.
Instead of fading out, I want the Div to slide Down off the screen.

Current Example is located here
http://jsbin.com/uwonun/45/

```
var elements = ['#pointsbarDiv', '#hotlink1Div','#pointsbarDiv', '#hotlink2Div'];

function anim_loop(index) {
    $(elements[index]).slideDown(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % elements.length);
        }, 5000);
    });
}

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element**strong text**
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: well, it's not going to slide off the screen if all you're doing is fading it out.. *"I have this green div, how do i make it yellow?"*

Comment: I wanted to change the animation from fade to slide. As Jwags has answered for me below.
However, now my problem is I want his animate to replace the slideDown in my code too.

Comment: my point was generally on stackoverflow you have to try to solve the problem yourself. We will then help you with any problems you come across while doing it. we aren't here to do it for you and answers simply saying "use .animate" aren't very useful.

Comment: I have been trying myself...I had even tried the animate(), etc myself but not in the way jwags had.

Comment: You should include those in your question next time to show that you have done your own research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to swap the fadeOut call for a call to [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  Here is an example setting the position top value to below the height of the screen

```
function anim_loop(index) {
  $(elements[index]).css({top: 0, display: 'none'}).slideDown(1000, function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $self.animate({top: $(window).height() + 100}, 1000);
      anim_loop((index + 1) % elements.length);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/uwonun/58/edit)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Just wondering...how could i implement the animate to replace the slideDown?

Comment: I would recommend reading the link to the jQuery animate documentation provided in my answer.  It's a good resource for learning about the different options you have for moving the DOM around.